# Removing duplicate entries from arralist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have an arraylist "Templist" after some point of time i saw lot of duplicate values are added to arraylist, so i thought of to remove duplicates.When i googled i found some solutions but most of them are confusing.Some where it is telling sort the arralist and find and remove duplicates some where telling to use distinct, somewhere telling to use hashlist. Any way i dont want to replace Arraylist with some other structures. Can anybody provide me logic to prevent duplicates from arraylist?

The code which now i am having is

```
 public class Templist : ArrayList
 {
   //some logic behind arraylist
 }                     Templist items = new Templist();

                       if (!(obj is Testobject) && !(obj is Leafobject))
                       {
                          items.Add(obj);
                       }


                    if (items.Count > 0)
                    {
                       SSendObjectCollection(items);
                    }

                static public void SendObjectCollection(Templist col)
                {
                  try 
                  {
                       col.Sort();
                  }
                    catch(System.Exception exception)
                    {
                    }

                }
```

**UPDATE**

i did this code

```
public static string[] RemoveDuplicates(string[] s)
 {
     HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(s);
     string[] result = new string[set.Count];
     set.CopyTo(result);
     return result;
 }
```

Then i called in exisitng function SendObjectCollection()
like `RemoveDuplicates(col);`
but it is throwing errors, can any body guide me what is going wrong here?

Comment: A few questions: Have you worked out *where* the duplicates are coming from? You've given us no context. Why are you using `ArrayList` in the first place? (Generic collections are almost always preferable.) Why are you *deriving* from `ArrayList`? (Deriving your own collection from the existing ones is almost always a bad idea.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet duplicate is getting in method SendObjectCollection, this arralist is customized arralist ,i will modify question

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list when you do so

Comment: @Jon Skeet updated my question

Comment: Is it essential that the elements in the list stay in the same order as the one in which they were added to the list? I really think, like Skeet, that you should reconsider and use a generic (hence type-safe) collection. If the order of addition to the list is not relevant, consider using a `SortedSet<T>` (no duplicates possible, elements are ordered by size) or a `HashSet<T>` (no duplicate, no order of the list elements, fast look-up to see if an item is a member of the list or not).

Comment: @vettori you probably want a class that *uses* an ArrayList, not one that *is* an ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems that you have to solve. Firstly you have to remove duplicate values by using:

```
myArray = new Arraylist(myArray.Distinct().ToArray());
```

and checking duplicate before add value to array list:

```
if(myArray.indexOf("value") == -1) {myArray.Add("value");}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Or `myArray.Contains("value")`

Comment: @Phong Vo can you modify based on my question, i am not getting Distinct() method even if i added system.Linq namespace

Comment: Sorry mate, it should be: `myArray = new Arraylist(myArray.ToArray().Distinct().ToArray());`

Comment: The old (.NET 1 style) type `ArrayList` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` for any `T` and therefore you can't use `.Distinct()` extension method directly. Calling `.ToArray()` immediately makes an unnecessary copy of the collection. Instead I would use `.Cast<object>().Distinct()` or even better `.Cast<RelevantType>().Distinct()` where `RelevantType` is a class (or other type) that you know all elements in the list are.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen but Distinct() has perfomance issues, i thought of to use HashSet but got some errors, i updated my question

Comment: @vettori What "performance issues" do you have in mind? Saying `new HashSet<string>(oldCollection)` like you do in your question update, will require more or less the same as `Distinct()` requires. You don't tell what errors are being thrown. That makes it hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please include more information, like where do you add item into ArrayList. Anyway, you can use

```
ArrayList.Contain(somevalue)
```

to check whether it existed in ArrayList before adding to avoid duplicating

Comment: if (!(obj is Testobject) && !(obj is Leafobject) && ArraList.indexOf(obj) == -1)

This will help you avoid duplication

Comment: will that work , because i am gettin lot of duplicates values, so i doubt this will prevent only first set of valiues only

Comment: The if statement above will check whether object already existed in your ArrayList or not every time you want to add object to it. So it can help you prevent duplication on adding object

Comment: The variable is called `items`, so you want to check `items.IndexOf(obj) == -1` or `!items.Contains(obj)` (`items.Contains(obj) == false`).